# WordPress 3.2.1: jQuery is not defined, breaks Admin panel

Tags: jquery

I've fresh-installed a WordPress 3.2.1 on my server yesterday. Unfortunately, installing 3.2.1 breaks all the jQuery scripts and I can't click on "Collapse menu", "HTML" in the editor, "Fullscreen" - basically, everything that's loaded with jQuery.

I've tested with Safari, Firefox and Chrome on a MAC OS X.

I downgraded on 3.2.0 and jQuery is working properly on this version, but when I upgrade back to 3.2.1. everything breaks.

If you think it's related to JSON, JSON is working properly with PHP, too. I also don't have any plugins installed, except Akismet and the theme installed with the default one: Tweenty Twelve or smtg.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: So you could send us the error, that the jQuery is outputing on the console.

Answer (score 1):

Twenty Eleven is the default theme and 3.2.1 is working fine for me here, on both a local machine and a server build.

Are you getting Wordpress directly from Wordpress.org? Also, make sure your default theme is twenty eleven and try that. If it is not, you may have a larger issue on your hands.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be working in the latest nightly build: development version (3.3-aortic-dissection).